# Python Pandas Dataframe - row level operations

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do a large number of row level operations (a few pages of code) on a table of data.

E.g.      `if  row.Col_A == 'X' : row.Col_B = 'Y'`

I believe iterrows  isn't appropriate for altering table values.
So I've converted the table to a list of DotMap dictionaries. With this I can loop over the list and for each dictionary (row), write the code as above and the alterations are saved.

Is it possible to do this with the data as a DataFrame ?

There is a lot of logic and I think its clearest written this way so I'd prefer not to use map or apply functions.

Comment: I like to use `for i, j in zip(df['A'], df['B']): if i == 1: j == 2` etc... You can loop through multiple columns in parallel with zip.

Comment: The underlying storage of a DataFrame is a collection of numpy arrays, so you can iterate over that. It is recommended not to do so for performance reasons, because Python loops are much slower than Pandas or numpy methods, but it is not worse than iterating over any other Python container (provided you directly access the dataframe and not a view over it so, you are true, `iterrows` should be avoided).

Comment: @SergeBallesta I agree, but there are situations where you cannot avoid looping, although, I think sometimes it is inevitable. I think that creating functions, apply(lambda x), pandas/numpy vectorized methods and list comprehension can do 95% of the job.

Comment: I have 20 columns and 20 operations to apply.  Can this be extended to all columns. Something like        for *df.columns in    df.itertuples():

Comment: @LincolnHannah as an alternative to looping. the Vectorized np.where() is one of the most powerful methods that I use constantly. I would look into that.

Comment: Readable logic is more important here than performance.  In David's Example I would use the column names A and B as the variables instead of i and j.   Nice thing about this approach is within the logic you don't even have to repeat the table or row name - its just the variable name.

Comment: @DavidErickson: I agree too. When the dataframe has a *reasonable* size, and/or when the logic is really complex, manual iteration can be better that `apply`, and lead to much more *maintainable* code. But a programmer should always think twice before going that way because it is far less efficient that `np.where` or any other vectorized method.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have 20 where statements.  I like David's zip approach because you just work with the variable names. The logic is written as though they are single variables rather than elements of a vector -    but can this be extended to 20 columns ?       Can the i,j be replaced by    a list of the column names ?

Comment: @LincolnHannah I think looping is completely fine for a pandas beginner, but in 1-2 months I would start to move away from it. It just depends. GL!

Answer (score 1):

Let's have the following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

some_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_a': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4],
    'col_b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'z', 'z']
})
```

We want to create a new column based on one (or more) of the existing columns' values.

In case you have only two options, I would suggest using numpy.where like this:

```
some_data['np_where_example'] = np.where(some_data.col_a < 3, 'less_than_3', 'greater_than_3')
print(some_data)
>>>
   col_a col_b           col_c map_example np_where_example  \
0      1     a     less_than_3         NaN      less_than_3   
1      2     b     less_than_3         BBB      less_than_3   
2      1     c     less_than_3         NaN      less_than_3   
3      2     c     less_than_3         NaN      less_than_3   
4      3     a  greater_than_3         NaN   greater_than_3   
5      4     b  greater_than_3         BBB   greater_than_3   
6      3     z  greater_than_3         ZZZ   greater_than_3   
7      4     z  greater_than_3         ZZZ   greater_than_3 

# multiple conditions
some_data['np_where_multiple_conditions'] = np.where(((some_data.col_a >= 3) & (some_data.col_b == 'z')),
                                                     'is_true',
                                                     'is_false')
print(some_data)
>>>
   col_a col_b np_where_multiple_conditions
0      1     a                     is_false
1      2     b                     is_false
2      1     c                     is_false
3      2     c                     is_false
4      3     a                     is_false
5      4     b                     is_false
6      3     z                      is_true
7      4     z                      is_true
```

In case you have many options, then pandas.map would be better:

```
some_data['map_example'] = some_data.col_b.map({
    'b': 'BBB',
    'z': 'ZZZ'
})
print(some_data)
>>>
   col_a col_b map_example
0      1     a         NaN
1      2     b         BBB
2      1     c         NaN
3      2     c         NaN
4      3     a         NaN
5      4     b         BBB
6      3     z         ZZZ
7      4     z         ZZZ
```

As you see, in all cases the values for which a condition is not specified evaluate to `NaN`.

Comment: I like np.where(). I feel like it is often overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function with a lambda in the following way:

```
df['Col_B'] = df['Col_A'].apply(lambda a: 'Y' if a == 'X' else 'N')
```

This creates the column Col_B on the dataframe df by looking at Col_A and giving either the values 'Y' if Col_A is 'X' and 'N' otherwise.

if your function is a bit more complex you can define it beforehand and call it in the apply function as follows:

```
def yes_or_no(x):
    if x == 'X':
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'
df['Col_B'] = df['Col_A'].apply(lambda a: yes_or_no(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to iterate over a dataframe by rows and change column values is:

1. make sure that there are no duplicated values in index (if there are, just use `reset_index` to get an acceptable index)
2. iterate over the index and access the individual values with `at`

   ```
    for ix in df.index:
        if df.at[ix, 'A'] == ...:
            df.at[ix, 'B'] = z
   ```

Alternatively, if you can access the columns by their positions instead of their names, you can use the even more efficient `iat`:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iat[i, index_col_A] == ... :
        df.iat[i, index_col_B] = z
```

As you access directly the individual elements, you avoid the overhead of `iterrows` creating a Series per row, and can perform changes. AFAIK, it is the less bad way when you cannot use the vectorized Pandas or numpy methods.